# Passing a header value as a property?

Tags: soapui

Is there a way in SoapUI Pro to transfer the value of a header property? We don't return XML data from the REST call, but we need information that comes in the raw response header. How to best access that?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To store values from the http header of the response message you'll need to use some Groovy script by adding a Groovy Script test step after your REST Request test step.

The code below will retrieve the value of a specific response header property:

```
def headerValue = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("testStepName").httpRequest.response.responseHeaders["headerPropertyName"]
```

Change the 'testStepName' and 'headerPropertyName' values to whatever is appropriate for your test.

If you want to use this value in further Test Steps you'll need to store it as a Test Property, the below link should cover everything you'll need:

http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/tips-a-tricks.html#1-1-get-and-set-properties